# How to implement Fiverrs DamnQuickPay functionality with Paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

I see that fiver have implemented an instant pay feature with paypal.  Does anyone have an idea how they implemented this?  I've had a quick look on google and on paypal and I can't see how they did this.

I do have a few services on my site linked with paypal for purchasing and I'd love to have this kind of functionality.

For those who are unsure what I mean, here is a link: http://blog.fiverr.com/tag/one-click/

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Paypal to pay for GoDaddy or iTunes, they setup something very similar.  I believe they use the [Adaptive Payments API](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/adaptive_payments).  One of the features includes:

> **Pre-approved payments.** Customers can pre-approve future payments.

Documentation for the API can be found here:

https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1419

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Fiverr's DamnQuickPay sucks - I got $10 lost without getting what I paid for. If you are not happy with it and want to cancel it inside your PayPal, here is how PayPal says about the cancellation procedure (fiverr won't tell you the details as to how):

How do I cancel an automatic payment I have with a merchant?

1. Log in to your PayPal account.
2. Click Profile at the top of the page.
3. Click My Money then click Update beside My preapproved payments to find your payment.
4. Select the payment, and then click Cancel.

That's it!